# Inferred type from type indexed by enum

Tags: typescript

I'm not sure how to explain what I mean, but this is what I have:

```js
enum ContactBaseType {
  Email,
  Notification
}

interface ContactBase {
  [ContactBaseType.Email]: EmailType[];
  [ContactBaseType.Notification]: NotificationType[];
}
```

What I want to do:

```js
function ToggleSubscription(lookup: ContactBase, type: ContactBaseType, enumType: EmailType | NotificationType) {

  // something like this, however this gives me a "EmailType | NotificationType is not assignable to never"
  const index = lookup[type].indexOf(enumType);
}
```

I've tried a few different solutions and none of them seem to work, so I think I'm missing something. I've tried using maps kind of like this:

```
type ContactBaseFlags = ContactBaseType.Email | ContactBaseType.Notification;
type ContactBaseMap = { [K in ContactBaseFlags]: K extends ContactBaseType.Email ? EmailType[] : NotificationType[] };

// or
type ContactBaseMap: { [K in ContactBaseFlags]: EmailType[] | NotificationType[] }
```

I've tried extracting the key, using keyof, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like that

```js
function ToggleSubscription<
  B extends ContactBase & {[key in T]: Array<I>}, // <- our base object
  T extends keyof B, // <- one of its keys
  I extends B[T] extends Array<infer U> ? U : never, // <- type of a related array
>(lookup: B, type: T, enumType: I) {
  // works now.
  const index = lookup[type].indexOf(enumType);
}
```